# "Inlining failed" error when activating BWA on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

I'm currently trying to activate the latest bwa package on my Virtualbox Linux Mint 64 bit. I have followed the instructions on the README file:

```
## Getting started

    git clone https://github.com/lh3/bwa.git
    cd bwa; make
```

but when I type "make" and press enter I get the following errors:

```
ksw.c: In function ‘ksw_u8’:
ksw.c:131:7: warning: SSE vector return without SSE enabled changes the ABI [-Wpsabi]
  zero = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
  ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:654:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_set1_epi8’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_set1_epi8 (char __A)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:136:8: note: called from here
  shift = _mm_set1_epi8(q->shift);
  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:654:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_set1_epi8’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_set1_epi8 (char __A)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:135:8: note: called from here
  e_ins = _mm_set1_epi8(_e_ins);
  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:654:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_set1_epi8’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_set1_epi8 (char __A)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:134:9: note: called from here
  oe_ins = _mm_set1_epi8(_o_ins + _e_ins);
  ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:654:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_set1_epi8’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_set1_epi8 (char __A)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:133:8: note: called from here
  e_del = _mm_set1_epi8(_e_del);
  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:654:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_set1_epi8’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_set1_epi8 (char __A)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:132:9: note: called from here
  oe_del = _mm_set1_epi8(_o_del + _e_del);
  ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:642:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_set1_epi32’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_set1_epi32 (int __A)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:131:7: note: called from here
  zero = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
  ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:713:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_store_si128’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_store_si128 (__m128i *__P, __m128i __B)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:142:3: note: called from here
   _mm_store_si128(Hmax + i, zero);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:713:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_store_si128’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_store_si128 (__m128i *__P, __m128i __B)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:141:3: note: called from here
   _mm_store_si128(H0 + i, zero);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:713:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_store_si128’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_store_si128 (__m128i *__P, __m128i __B)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:140:3: note: called from here
   _mm_store_si128(E + i, zero);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:1191:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_slli_si128’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_slli_si128 (__m128i __A, const int __N)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:149:5: note: called from here
   h = _mm_slli_si128(h, 1); // h=H(i-1,-1); << instead of >> because x64 is little-endian
   ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:695:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_load_si128’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_load_si128 (__m128i const *__P)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:148:5: note: called from here
   h = _mm_load_si128(H0 + slen - 1); // h={2,5,8,11,14,17,-1,-1} in the above example
   ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:695:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_load_si128’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_load_si128 (__m128i const *__P)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:174:6: note: called from here
    h = _mm_load_si128(H0 + j); // h=H'(i-1,j)
    ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:1377:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_max_epu8’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_max_epu8 (__m128i __A, __m128i __B)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:172:6: note: called from here
    f = _mm_max_epu8(f, t);
    ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ksw.c:29:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include/emmintrin.h:1100:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_subs_epu8’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_subs_epu8 (__m128i __A, __m128i __B)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
ksw.c:171:6: note: called from here
    t = _mm_subs_epu8(h, oe_ins); // h=H'(i,j) - o_ins - e_ins
    ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The entire error message is too long to be pasted, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade make gcc zlib1g-dev` should do it. Let me explain why it think this:

*If it didn't help and you are only interested in the solution for this exact case, jump to the end of my answer.*

I usually solve build issues with docker so that I can create a minimized environment of my distribution.

You are building for Mint which is basically Ubuntu plus extra's. I'll assume your version is Mint 19, which is based on Ubuntu 18.04 so I run `docker run --name bwabuild -it --rm ubuntu:18.04`. From now one I run all mentioned commands inside the container:

- I need git: `apt-get update && apt-get install git`
- I need the repo: `git clone https://github.com/lh3/bwa.git && cd bwa`
- I need to parse the makefile: `apt-get install make`

From here on I just run `make` over-and-over and always handle the first new error that I see. These are the problems I noticed and have to solve:

- no gcc: `apt-get install gcc`
- no zlib.h: `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`
  I found out that this is the package needed by searching for `zlib.h` on the 'real' system (it was at `/usr/include/zlib.h`) and running `dpkg -S /usr/include/zlib.h` on the 'real' system

From here on it builds correctly (with warnings, but that's just because the code is 'ugly'). I received no errors. So now i check the package versions:

- `dpkg -l make` : 4.1-9.1ubuntu1
- `dpkg -l gcc`: 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3
- `dpkg -l zlib1g-dev`: 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2

I now know which packages i need and what the version should be, so I `exit` the container (which also kills it because i ran it with `--rm`) .

I update these 3 packages on my hostsystem (coincidentally I also use Mint) and try to build in the same way you did and it now builds perfectly.

If for some reason it still doesn't build on your system, you can do it in a docker container like i did. This will certainly work because the environment will be exactly the same as in my case.
After the build is done (and before you exit the container), use a 2nd terminal in which you run `docker cp bwabuild:/root/bwa/bwa .` to copy your the bwa-program from within the container to your current directory.

Be warned: This last solution will for certain work to build it, but not necessaliy to run it. The program was build with the assumption certain libraries are at certain places. The location of these libs in your host system and in your container might be different (although it would surprise me because they are both based on Ubuntu 18.04)

**EDIT**:

I just noticed that this program can also be installed with conda: `conda install -c bioconda bwa`